# POSIX print function definition

Tags: shell, function, posix

Bash can print a function defintion:

```
$ bash -c 'y(){ echo z; }; export -f y; export -f'
y ()
{
    echo z
}
declare -fx y
```

However this fails under POSIX Bash, */bin/sh* and */bin/dash*:

```
$ bash --posix -c 'y(){ echo z; }; export -f y; export -f'
export -f y
```

Can a function definition be printed under a POSIX shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not do it portably. POSIX spec did not specify any way to dump function definition, nor how functions are implemented.

---

In `bash`, you don't have to export the function to the environment, you can use:

```
declare -f funcname
```

(Work in `zsh`)

This works even you run `bash` in `posix` mode:

```
$ bash --posix -c 'y(){ echo z; }; declare -f y'
y () 
{ 
    echo z
}
```

---

In `ksh`:

```
typeset -f funcname
```

(Works in `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `pdksh`, `lksh`)

---

In `yash`:

```
typeset -fp funcname
```

This won't work if `yash` enter [POSIXly-correct mode](https://yash.osdn.jp/doc/posix.html):

```
$ yash -o posixly-correct -c 'y() { ehco z; }; typeset -fp y'
yash: no such command `typeset'
```

---

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- $functions[funcname]
whence -f funcname
type -f funcname
which funcname
```

Note that both `whence -f`, `which`, `type -f` will report alias first with the same name. You can use `-a` to make `zsh` report all definitions.

---

POSIXly, you'd have to record your function definition yourself which you could do with:

```
myfunction_code='myfunction() { echo Hello World; }'
eval "$myfunction_code"
```

or a helper function

```
defn() {
  code=$(cat)
  eval "${1}_code=\$code; $1() { $code; }"
}

defn myfunction << 'EOF'
echo Hello World
EOF

printf '%s\n' "$myfunction_code"
```

Comment: @schily recently opened http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1025 for that.

Answer (score 1):

No. At least, not to my knowledge.

`-f` is an extension to [POSIX export](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export).

POSIX `set` (and `bash` `set` in POSIX mode) also excludes function definitions.