# FreeBSD's sh: List functions

Tags: shell, freebsd, function

What is FreeBSD's `/bin/sh` equivalent to `bash`'s:

```
compgen -A function
```

which lists the names of the declared functions.

Comment: Don't put multiple questions into a single question.  Anyway, that is already answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322035/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145522/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD's `/bin/sh` is the Almquist shell, and it has no equivalent to that because the Almquist shell does not have programmable command completion in the first place.

However, if you were looking for an equivalent for `typeset -F` you would still be out of luck.  The Almquist shell has no built-in command for listing the names of available shell functions.

This is in fact the same question as "[ash: List functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343316/)" and "[dash: List declared functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343297/)".  The Debian Almquist shell, the FreeBSD Almquist shell, and the BusyBox Almquist shell *are all the Almquist shell*.  Whilst there *are* differences amongst them (in particular the `setvar` builtin, the `let` builtin, and suchlike) they do not extend to a difference in *this* respect.

In fact, no flavour of the Almquist shell has this.  So you probably do not need to ask this a fourth time about another Almquist shell.  ☺

## Further reading

- Sven Maschek (2014-10-11). *[`ash` variants](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/)*. in-ulm.de.
- [POSIX print function definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268297/)